# Consecutive integers based question

Tags: number-theory

Which of the following statements is/are true?

1. There are 3 consecutive integers with sum 2015
2. There are 4 consecutive integers with sum 2015
3. There are 5 consecutive integers with sum 2015
4. There are 3 consecutive integers with product 2015

I tried and I got 3rd one is right and 1 and 2 are wrong but I stuck in option three I am not able to conclude the option 4 is right or wrong?

Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #4:

For three consecutive integers, at least one must be even (divisible by $2$) and exactly one must be divisible by $3$.

Hence any product of three consecutive digits must be divisible by $2 \times 3$, or $6$.

$2015$ is not divisible by $6$

Comment: Thank you sir @ DjohnM

Comment: Wow, brilliantly simple. I love it. Minor nitpick though, should be $2015$ on the last line (though it applies to both lol)

Comment: Divisibility by $2$ or $3$ is enough, since $2015$ is divisible by neither

Comment: @EeveeTrainer  Thanks,,, Done...

Answer (score 2):

Generalise it like this: There are $n$ consecutive integers with sum $s$. You get the equation:
$$x+(x+1)+(x+2)+...+(x+n-1)=s$$
It is a linear equation, so it is both easy to solve and it can't have more than one sollution. If the sollution is an integer, the answer is yes, otherwise the answer is false.

For the product, you get:
$$x\cdot(x+1)\cdot(x+2)\cdot...\cdot(x+n-1)=p$$
where $p$ is the desired product. If any of the solutions is an integer, the answer is yes, else the answer is no.

Comment: It's a little easier when you do $(x-k) + (x-k-1) + ... + (x + k)$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exists some integer $n$ such that it and its four successive integers sum to $2015$: then

$$n+(n+1)+(n+2)+(n+3)+(n+4) = 5n+10 = 2015$$

Solve for $n$. You should be able to conclude $n$ is an integer and thus five consecutive integers sum to $2015$.

In general, if you want to see if $k$ consecutive numbers sum up to some number $S$, we consider the equation

$$n+(n+1)+(n+2)+\cdots+(n+k-1) = S$$

and try to see what $n$ satisfies this equation. If no integer does, then no set of $k$ consecutive integers could add up to $S$.

---

Can three consecutive integers multiply to $2015$? We try a similar strategy: consider $n$ and the numbers succeeding it. Then we want $n$ such that

$$n(n+1)(n+2) = 2015$$

From here, you can solve for $n$ by your method of choice. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+n+n(n%2B1)(n%2B2)%3D2015) shows none of the three solutions to this are integers. Thus, no three consecutive numbers multiply to $2015$.

Comment: More generally, if there are an odd number of consecutive numbers that sum to a number, that number must be divisible by that odd number. If there is an even number of consecutive numbers, then the number mod the even number is the even number / 2

Comment: the above three consecutive integers product solving I need by hand ..It is a competetive exam question in that place u can't use Wolfram Alpha

Comment: $n(n+1)(n+2)$ is about $(n+1)^3$.  You might know that $2048=2^{12}=16^3$.  Then you can check $n=14,15$, find that neither works, and declare victory.

Comment: This is a minor issue but, instead of $n(n+1)(n+2)$, I would generally use the slightly simpler $(n-1)n(n+1) = (n^2 - 1)n = n^3 - n$.